# Is Steam required to install and or play a physical disc of Dragon Ball Xenoverse 2 on PC?

Tags: steam, dragon-ball-xenoverse-2

If I buy a physical disc copy of Dragon Ball Xenoverse 2 for PC is Steam required to install and or play the game?

Answer (score 0):

If it is at all similar to any other Steam game that has been released with a physical CD, then yes.

A friend bought a physical copy of a different game, and it simply directed him to install Steam and enter the key code.

So most likely, yes. I can't seem to even find a physical copy of it, which makes it much more likely it will just be a Steam code bundled in a CD.

Comment: It's not out yet, but I noticed that none of the preorders mention Steam, but everything about the previous entry in the series has "for PC (via Steam only)" tacked onto it. I don't think Steam will be required for this.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the back side of your physical disc package. There should be a steam logo, if steam is required.